# Remove lines that don't contain X in a excel file?

Tags: linux, csv

At the moment I am using the following to remove certain keywords.

sed -i '/THISGETSDELETED/d' my.csv

However now I want to do it the other way around and only keep the lines of data that have X in the Excel line.

However I have multiple keywords. What would the command be to do this plus with multiple keywords?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this with `egrep`

```
egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" excel.csv > tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ excel.csv
```

Or with `sed`

```
sed -e '/pattern1/b' -e '/pattern2/b' -e '/pattern3/b' -e 'd' excel.csv
```